# How to load JSON file from API call to S3 bucket without using Secret Access Key and ID ? looking for common industry practice

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am making calls to API using `python` `request` library, and I am receiving the response in `JSON`. Currently I am saving `JSON` response on local computer, what I would like to do is to load `JSON` response directly to `s3` bucket. The reason for loading to `s3` bucket is my `s3` bucket is acting as source to parse the `JSON` response for relational output. I was wondering how can I load `JSON` file directly to `s3` bucket without using Access key or secret key ?

Most of my research on this topic lead to using`boto3` in `python`. Unfortunately, this library also requires key and  ID. The reason for not using secret key and ID is because my organization has separate department which takes care of giving access to `s3` bucket, and the department can only create IAM role with  read and write access. I am curious what is the common industry practice of loading `JSON` in your organization ?

Comment: Have a component, like a Lambda, decide if you have access via some business rules validation and/or credential access, and if so, give you a presigned URL to upload the file to S3.

Answer (score 0):

You can make unsigned requests for S3 through [VPC Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/privatelink-interface-endpoints.html#types-of-vpc-endpoints-for-s3) (VPCE), and don't need any AWS credentials this way.

```
# https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-example-privatelink.html
s3 = boto3.client('s3', config=Config(signature_version=UNSIGNED), endpoint_url="https://bucket.vpce-xxx-xxx.s3.ap-northeast-1.vpce.amazonaws.com")
```

You can restrict source ip by setting security group in VPC Endpoint to protect your S3 Bucket. Note that the owner of s3 objects uploaded by unsigned requests is anonymous, and may cause some side effects. In my case, Lifecycle rules cannot apply to those s3 objects.